# Using interface name in interface members C#

Tags: c#, interface, member

I have four classes as:

`Author.cs` class i.e.

```
public class Author : Interfaces.INode
{
        public int _aID { get; set; }
        public string _aName { get; set; }
        public List<CoAuthor> _aCoAuthors { get; set; }
        public List<Venue> _aVenue { get; set; }
        public List<Paper> _aPapers { get; set; }

        public string _aArea { get; set; }
}
```

`CoAuthor.cs` class i.e.

```
public class CoAuthor : Interfaces.INode
{
        public int _coaID { get; set; }
        public string _coaName { get; set; }
        public List<Paper> _coaPapers { get; set; }

        public string _coaArea { get; set; }
}
```

`Venue.cs` class i.e.

```
public class Venue : Interfaces.INode
{
    public int _vID { get; set; }
    public string _vName { get; set; }
    public List<Paper> _vPapers { get; set; }

    public string _vArea { get; set; }
}
```

`Paper.cs` class i.e.

```
public class Paper : Interfaces.INode
{
    public int _pID { get; set; }
    public Author _pAuthor { get; set; }
    public List<CoAuthor> _pCoAuthors { get; set; }
    public Venue _pVenue { get; set; }
    public int _pYear { get; set; }
    public string _pRField { get; set; }
}
```

All of these classes are implementing an `interface` i.e. `Interfaces.INode` which is defined as:

```
public interface INode
{
        List<INode> _TargetObject { get; }
        List<INode> _AttributeObject { get; }
}
```

Now `Author.cs` class is of type `_TargetObject` i.e. defined in `INode` and all of the other 3 classes are of type `_AttributeObject` i.e. defined in `INode`.

*How can I link these classes with corresponding `INode` members as currently its not clear that which are `_TargetObject` and `_AttributeObject`?*

Comment: You should be able to check the type and cast it.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen How this casting will be implemented ? Will it be in `class` or in `interface` definitions ?

Comment: What is the purpose of using `interface` name i.e. `INode` in members as `List<INode>`?

Comment: there is something strange in inode interface definition and in list properties definition. If 3 classes are grouped and author is out of that group, one more interface should exist. I suppose one interface (empty) IAttribute : INode. So you can define with more precision what classes are intended to used in _AttributeObject list or in _TargetObjectList.

Comment: @Othello.netdev may be you right but one thing more I want to add that `_TargetObject` and `_AttributeObject` lists are nodes of same graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in comment, i suggest you to define better objects and tiping. In this implementation you have more control of what types are Target and what are attributes

```
public interface INode
{
        List<INode> _TargetObject { get; }
        List<IAttribute> _AttributeObject { get; }
}  

public interface IAttribute : INode
{

}  

public class Author : Interfaces.INode
{
     private List<INode> _targetList ;
     private List<IAttribute> _attributeObject ;
     public Author()
     {
         _targetList = new List<INode>();
     }
     //implementazion of _TargetObject INode method
     public List<INode> _TargetObject 
     { 
         get  
         {
             return _targetList;
         }
     }
     //implementazion of _AttributeObject INode method
     public List<IAttribute> _AttributeObject 
     { 
         get  
         {
             return _attributeObject ;
         }
     }

} 

public class CoAuthor : Interfaces.IAttribute 
{... your class implementation ...}
public class Venue : Interfaces.IAttribute
{... your class implementation ...}
public class Paper : Interfaces.IAttribute
{... your class implementation ...}
```

Comment: Then what to place inside `public interface IAttribute : INode` interface?

Comment: Actually you are trying to separate out the Target and Attribute objects ? 
Whereas both are nodes of same graph, so will there not be something wrong regarding implementation point of view as we have to implement a graph here

Comment: How will we implement interface member Lists in classes ?

Comment: IAttribute may be empty, is a "type placeholder", ready for future use. IAttribute also implementes INode, so you can use as INode or IAttribute as your specifics need. One object implementing IAttribute is also a INode class but not vice versa. In some examples you can found something as Lion is  IAnimal and IFeline but a dog is only IAnimal and not a IFeline... If you create one List<IAnimal> you can fill it with Lion and Dog but if you create one List<IFeline> only Lion object may be inserted...

Comment: Its mean both Target and Attributes may be gathered for graph implementation furthermore

Comment: But shouldn't we have to implement (define) `List<INode> _TargetObject` and `List<IAttribute> _AttributeObject` in classes which are implementing `INode` and `IAttribute` ?

Comment: You have defined a INode interface. Every object that is one INode must implement public methods defined. IAttribute inherits from INode, IAttribute IS INode, so the implementation requirements are the same.

Comment: As there are no public methods in interfaces but public member Lists so should these Lists be also implemented ?

Comment: Interface may be implemented in 2 ways http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000374/Explicit-Interface-VS-Implicit-Interface-in-Csharp in both methods the implementation will be accessible outside of the class. I prefer implicit implementation, i found it more clear.

Comment: Its fine to prefer implicit implementation but the question is how to implement a `List<INode> _TargetObject` as declared in `INode` interface? Should the list is to be initialized with some value or what I have to insert in this List to get it implemented whereas `Author` class is of type `_TargetObject` ?

Comment: OR all of the members of class `Author` should be in the List `List<INode> _TargetObject` ?

Comment: changed the example with INode implementation

Comment: @Othello--Thanks! :)

Comment: One thing more, i.e. when we implement other 3 classes will the implementation for `Interfaces.IAttribute` remain same ?

Comment: i think about yes... (why you don't create a common base class AttributeImpl as a base class of the 3?)

Comment: @Othello--I have an update to your answer for implementing `IAttribute` interface for rest of the classes, is it right ?

Comment: That's why its disappeared :( anyhow